# Null argument values passed from HTML form to WCF REST function

Tags: .net, wcf, rest, forms

I have created a RESTful WCF service with a method that will be used to save data using a POST. I want to test this method from an HTML form. The following HTML form and interface definition (and related .cs code) result in the `SaveTest` function getting called when I hit the form `Submit` button, however the one argument `id` is always set to null.

HTML form:

```
<form action="http://localhost:1378/MyService.svc/SaveTest" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="id"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Interface definition:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "SaveTest")]
Stream SaveTest(string id);
```

What am I missing here?

### Edit

Our WCF service has some other methods that use GET that are working without any issues

i.e. `[WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetByTransactionID/{transactionID}")]`

Comment: Does it work with GET? Set the UriTemplate to "SaveTest?id={id}"

Comment: Yes, it works happily with GET (I've updated my post accordingly)